# How does spell levelling work with multiclassing?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, damage, multi-classing, cantrips

Suppose I am a level 10 rogue and take a level of sorcerer, giving me the firebolt cantrip. Normally, on a successful hit, the target takes 1d10 fire damage. Furthermore, the description says:

> This spell's damage increases by 1d10 when you reach 5th level (2d10), 11th level (3d10), and 17th level (4d10).

How much damage should I be rolling? 1d10, because I am a level 1 sorcerer? Or 3d10 because I have attained 11 levels?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Please check whether the linked question matches yours; if not, please edit to clarify what's not already addressed there.